# undefined reference to qt_static_plugin_QWaylandEglStreamBufferIntegrationPlugin

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debian, qt5

Got the following error while building Qt 5.12.7 in `static` mode, on Debian 10 32 bits:

```
error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QWaylandEglStreamBufferIntegrationPlugin()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [Makefile:80: qwindow-compositor] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/user/qt/static/qtwayland/examples/wayland/qwindow-compositor'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:59: sub-qwindow-compositor-make_first] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/qt/static/qtwayland/examples/wayland'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:47: sub-wayland-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/qt/static/qtwayland/examples'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:74: sub-examples-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/qt/static/qtwayland'
make: *** [Makefile:600: module-qtwayland-make_first] Error 2
```

I configured with the following options:

```
$ ../qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -opensource -static -qt-xcb -confirm-license -skip qtwebengine
```

Anybody can give me a hint on what's going on?

Non `static` build went fine, I did it just before.